# Like %?% doesn't work as part of StringBuilder SQL query

Tags: java, sql, string, sql-like

Have following String built SQL query:

```
    StringBuilder querySelect = new StringBuilder("select * from messages ");
    StringBuilder queryWhere = new StringBuilder("where msg_id=?");

        if (fileRSVO.getFileName()!= null){
            queryWhere.append("and descr LIKE %?% ");
        }
querySelect.append(queryWhere);

    List<Map<String, Object>> list = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(querySelect.toString(), params.toArray()); 
    ...
```

The problem is in this part:

```
queryWhere.append("and descr LIKE %?% ")
```

`LIKE` doesn't work.
Checked in debug - it's added to all query.
Should it be single quoted or some other trick?

thanks.

**EDITED**

tried single quotes:`queryWhere.append("and descr LIKE '%?%' ")`
doesn't work

here is debug string:

```
select * from messages where msg_id=? and descr LIKE '%?%'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?` is not a placeholder for textual substitution, it's a parameter (i.e. it's like variable in Java), therefore it should be treated as a separate token. This should work, but perhaps not in all databases:

```
queryWhere.append("and descr LIKE ('%' || ? || '%')");
```

Alternativelty you can pass `%`s as parts of parameter value, as suggested by Justin Muller.

Comment: queryWhere.append("and descr LIKE '%" + fileRSVO.getFileName()+ "%'") - that it is, anyway you direction is correct

Comment: @serionni: It's a very bad solution, it's vulnerable to SQL injections. Use either my soluton (add `%`s at the database side), or Justin Muller's one (add `%`s when you put `fileRSVO.getFileName()` into `params`).

Comment: @sergionni: Note the correction, this way it should be more compatible with databases.

Comment: @axtavt what does this syntax || mean in this context?

Comment: @sergionni: `||` is a standard SQL string concatenation operator.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the query is run using a `PreparedStatement`, the problem is probably that `queryForList` calls `setString(1, 'some descr')`.  This would resolve the SQL to `"... and descr LIKE %'some descr'%"`.

Try altering the code to:

```
queryWhere.append("and descr LIKE ?");
...
.setString(1, "%some descr%")
```

Comment: sorry, don't quite understand, where should I do setSetring()?

Comment: I guessing that somewhere in the queryForList(String, Array) method a call to setString(int, String) is made.

Answer (score 3):

can you try like this, and see anything changes.

```
queryWhere.append("and descr LIKE '%?%' ")
```

Comment: just checking... mvn is so slooow

Comment: unfortunately,not yet, see, please, EDITED part

Comment: got:org.springframework.jdbc.InvalidResultSetAccessException and java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index

Comment: sorry dont have any idea about those error messages. Are you positive that you are building your query string correctly ?

Comment: @futile: He wants `?` to be a parameter, not a part of literal. In this case your suggestion is incorrect.

Comment: @axtavt yes,you're right? it should be parameter, I already guessed it)

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to do

```
queryWhere.append("AND descr LIKE'%?%'");
```

I wrapped %?% in single quotes.

To see more LIKE query examples, checkout [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php).

Comment: strange,doesn't work with single quotes. Debug:select * from messages where msg_id=?  and descr LIKE '%?%'

Answer (score 2):

I always take the parameter and put the `%` into the parameter, and then bind it to `and descr like ?`.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder querySelect = new StringBuilder("select * from messages");
StringBuilder queryWhere = new StringBuilder("where msg_id=?");
if (fileRSVO.getFileName()!= null){
  queryWhere.append("and descr LIKE %?% ");
}
// query = "select * from messageswhere msg_id=?and descr LIKE %?% "
```

As you can see, the query is not valid. You must add spaces:

```
StringBuilder querySelect = new StringBuilder("select * from messages ");
StringBuilder queryWhere = new StringBuilder("where msg_id=? ");
if (fileRSVO.getFileName()!= null){
  queryWhere.append("and descr LIKE %?% ");
}
// query = "select * from messages where msg_id=? and descr LIKE %?% "
```

And about the part: descr LIKE %?%

I am not exactly sure how this is passed throught to the database. Just "as is", or as a 2nd parameter that needs to be filled in.
If "as is", the ? is seen as a wild-card and all results are taken.
If not, the 2nd ? is not filled in (correctly). Try using:

```
descr LIKE ?
```

And add the % before and after the value in you java code.

Comment: there are spaces there, it's simplified sample of my query

Answer (score 0):

If using a [third party library to manage dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370818/521799) is an option for you, here's a solution that uses [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org) (disclaimer: I work for the vendor)

```java
ctx.selectFrom(MESSAGES)
   .where(MESSAGES.MSG_ID.eq(msgId))
   .and(fileRSVO.getFileName() != null
      ? MESSAGES.DESCR.contains(descr)
      : DSL.noCondition())
   .fetch();
```

This is using the [`Field.contains(T)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#contains-T-) method, which translates to:

```sql
[ field ] like ('%' || escape(value, '\') || '%') escape '\'
```

Notice the usage of `escape()`, which is necessary in case your string contains wildcards. Another option would be, of course, to concatenate the wildcards already in Java:

```java
ctx.selectFrom(MESSAGES)
   .where(MESSAGES.MSG_ID.eq(msgId))
   .and(fileRSVO.getFileName() != null
      ? MESSAGES.DESCR.like("%" + descr + "%")
      : DSL.noCondition())
   .fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

funciona de esta forma

```
             sql.append(" AND VNOMBRE LIKE :P_VNOMBRE");
             parametros.addValue("P_VNOMBRE", "%"+oficinas.getCAJABUSQUEDA()+"%");
```

Comment: In stackoverflow.com, please use the English language. There are other language-specific variants, as https://es.stackoverflow.com/ for discussions in Spanish.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
StringBuilder querySelect = new StringBuilder("select * from messages ");
StringBuilder queryWhere = new StringBuilder("where msg_id=?");

if (fileRSVO.getFileName()!= null){
    queryWhere.append("and descr LIKE %?% ");
}
querySelect.append(queryWhere);

List<Map<String, Object>> list = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(querySelect.toString(), params.toArray()); 
...
```