# SQL Builders in Java

Tags: java, sql

I am currently shopping around for SQL builders in Java. My basic desire is something like this:

```
SelectBuilder sb = new SelectBuilder(source, alias); // Source can be subquery
sb.select(column1, alias1);
sb.select(column2, alias2);
sb.joinWith(joinObj, joinAlias);
sb.where(column1, operator, value)
sb.orderBy(column1, DESC)
// etc etc etc
```

... and that it does prepared statements

I've looked into JOOQ and my impression is that it is too convoluted for my taste. I don't want to set up some xml or xsd file for my schemas. The most I'd allow is to write the beans. I've looked at Squiggle but it only supports SELECT and not the rest. MyBatis is not good enough because it does not fully abstract out the SQL syntax. I've also tried several more recommended by Stack Overflow posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370818/cleanest-way-to-build-an-sql-string-in-java) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623607/dynamic-sql-java-library).

One additional thing that I really don't like about several Java-based SQL builder is the chaining syntax: i.e. select().from().where().etc().etc().etc()

Anyway, do you guys know of other SQL Builders that may meet my requirements? I've searched two days on web and couldn't find anything yet. Insight would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 12):

> I've looked into JOOQ and my impression is that it is too convoluted for my taste

What does that even mean? :)

> I don't want to set up some xml or xsd file for my schemas

You don't have to. You can use jOOQ without the code generator as documented here:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/use-cases/jooq-as-a-standalone-sql-builder

However, you will be missing out on tons of useful features if you don't use the code generator. How's the saying? [Hours of writing code manually saves seconds of setting up the code generator.](https://twitter.com/lukaseder/status/1065607719665709056) For even more convincing arguments about [why you should use the code generator, read this article here](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/).

> One additional thing that I really don't like about several Java-based SQL builder is the chaining syntax: i.e. select().from().where().etc().etc().etc()

Why not? It really helps. But then again, you don't have to. jOOQ has 2 APIs. The DSL API (which you don't like) and the model API. See this page here:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/dsl-and-non-dsl

Comment: Can it be used with any database? or only open source

Comment: @Makky: Check the list of supported database products by jOOQ edition here: https://www.jooq.org/download/#databases

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these:

http://www.querydsl.com/

https://github.com/ivanceras/fluent-sql

Also Hibernate Criteria API has fluent interface.
To my experience if the query is anything more complicated than select  from sometable then these fluent api-s make sql very unreadable.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've looked at QueryDSL already and it is not very different to JOOP. Hibernate is something I am trying to stay away since it involves too much setup. What I am mostly interested in is some form of String Builder that builds according the rules of SQL syntax through a easy-to-read functions. I've used one that's great but that's built-in house for .NET and not open to public.

Comment: We also have one in-house ORM-like tool development for Java that we plan to open-source within february. That is not entirely fluent api but it hides away table and field-column mappings. One could easily write select <all fields> from <table name> where <some field equals something> without sql. It relies on java persistence annotations to do the table and field-column mappings. 
And of course the more complex queries can be written in sql as well

Comment: You know. Maybe it's just me, but it seems like many people I know have their own in-house ORM that is more light weight and flexible than those available online for Java. Very strange. It's like having all these little dev companies re-inventing the wheel. My own workplace has its own SQL Builder and it is many times better than the likes of JOOP. I wonder why the open source community in Java lags behind so much in this domain.

Comment: @user1836155: I've spent the last 10 years doing only jOOQ. I'm *very* curious about what your company does so much better. Are you thinking of a very specific use-case? Then perhaps. But for general purpose SQL query building? I sincerely doubt it :)