# SQL Query builder utility

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, database

I have a Set of columns and Tables, in respective drop downs, I am working on a Code to generate a dynamic SQL based on the Table-Column selection

It's working in case of simple Select statements but in the case of Multiple Joins, I am trying to figure out a Syntax for handlin Right and Left Joins.

Please help..this is the Error for SQL Syntax

```
1)
(Select dbo.Employee.Dept_ID,dbo.Employee.Emp_ID,dbo.Employee.Emp_Name,dbo.Employee_DataVal.DeptNo,
dbo.Employee_DataVal.EmpName,dbo.Employee_DataVal.EmpNo,dbo.Employee_DataVal.Salary,dbo.Emp_Sal.Emp_ID,dbo.Emp_Sal.Salary
FROM Employee
INNER JOIN Employee_DataVal
ON Employee.Dept_ID = Employee_DataVal.DeptNo
OR Employee_DataVal.EmpName = Employee.Emp_Name)
LEFT JOIN Emp_Sal
ON Employee.Emp_ID = Emp_Sal.Emp_ID

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'.

2)Select dbo.Employee.Dept_ID,dbo.Employee.Emp_ID,
dbo.Employee.Emp_Name,dbo.Employee_DataVal.DeptNo,
dbo.Employee_DataVal.EmpName,dbo.Employee_DataVal.EmpNo
,dbo.Emp_Sal.Emp_ID,dbo.Emp_Sal.Salary
FROM Employee INNER JOIN Employee_DataVal
ON Employee.Emp_ID = Employee_DataVal.EmpNo
AND Employee.Dept_ID = Employee_DataVal.DeptNo
LEFT JOIN Employee
ON Employee_DataVal.EmpName = Employee.Emp_Name

The objects "Employee" and "Employee" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.
```

PS: Running this sql on SQL server

Comment: Do as the error says :-) Give you db a temp name, so this FROM Employee INNER JOIN Employee_DataVal becomes FROM Employee e INNER JOIN Employee_DataVal, then just prefix your fields

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, As I mentioned, I have to build a dynamic query, so at any instant if a User adds a Right Join from UI between a different table XTable, then how shall I proceed? Syntax wise and also Programatically in java?

Answer (score 4):

This is a common problem when working with complex dynamic SQL strings on a string basis - the correct handling of the SQL syntax in its string form is difficult, and it is easy to create SQL injection vulnerabilities as well.

SQL builder APIs like [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org) and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370818/521799) are very well suited for this task. I'm not sure what exactly the problem was in your case, but let's just assume that the last `LEFT JOIN` is optional in your query. You could write a query like this:

```java
List<Field<?>> c = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
    EMPLOYEE.DEPT_ID,
    EMPLOYEE.EMP_ID,
    EMPLOYEE.EMP_NAME,
    EMPLOYEE_DATAVAL.DEPTNO,
    EMPLOYEE_DATAVAL.EMPNAME,
    EMPLOYEE_DATAVAL.EMPNO,
    EMPLOYEE_DATAVAL.SALARY
));
Table<?> t = EMPLOYEE
   .join(EMPLOYEE_DATAVAL)
     .on(EMPLOYEE.DEPT_ID.eq(EMPLOYEE_DATAVAL.DEPTNO)
     .or(EMPLOYEE_DATAVAL.EMPNAME.eq(EMPLOYEE.EMP_NAME));

if (someCondition) {
    t = t.leftJoin(EMP_SAL).on(EMPLOYEE.EMP_ID.eq(EMP_SAL.EMP_ID));
    c.addAll(Arrays.asList(
        EMP_SAL.EMP_ID,
        EMP_SAL.SALARY
    ));
}

Result<?> result =
ctx.select(c)
   .from(t)
   .fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Speaking directly to the syntax errors:

1. The parentheses in this statement are invalid. Removing them will solve the problem.
2. The table Employee is used twice in the FROM clause. You must alias the tables for this to work.

   Select dbo.Employee.Dept_ID,dbo.Employee.Emp_ID,
   dbo.Employee.Emp_Name,dbo.Employee_DataVal.DeptNo,
   dbo.Employee_DataVal.EmpName,dbo.Employee_DataVal.EmpNo
   ,dbo.Emp_Sal.Emp_ID,dbo.Emp_Sal.Salary
   FROM Employee e1 INNER JOIN Employee_DataVal
   ON e1.Emp_ID = Employee_DataVal.EmpNo
   AND e1.Dept_ID = Employee_DataVal.DeptNo
   LEFT JOIN Employee e2
   ON Employee_DataVal.EmpName = e2.Emp_Name

Speaking to your broader question, the concept of a generic SQL query generator is quite common and has had several implementation. You won't find full implementation guidance in a forum such as this.

Cheers!

Comment: "the concept of a generic SQL query generator is quite common and has had several implementation" Can you please suggest some links for the same? That would really give me the cue to proceed further! Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this codeproject post will get your juices flowing. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13419/SelectQueryBuilder-Building-complex-and-flexible-S

Answer (score 0):

You are using LEFT Join same as the Self join. which is actually creating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In first case error is coming because of the wrong `)` in wrong place as pointed below; Which making the end of query and so `LEFT JOIN` throwing an error. the `)` must be at end of the query.

```
FROM Employee
INNER JOIN Employee_DataVal
ON Employee.Dept_ID = Employee_DataVal.DeptNo
OR Employee_DataVal.EmpName = Employee.Emp_Name ) <--Here
LEFT JOIN Emp_Sal
```

In second case, you are trying to do a `self join` to the same table in that case as the error already suggested you, you need to use `correlation names` like

```
FROM Employee emp1 <-- Here used a table alias emp1
INNER JOIN Employee_DataVal ed
ON emp1.Emp_ID = ed.EmpNo
AND emp.Dept_ID = ed.DeptNo
LEFT JOIN Employee emp2 <-- Here used a different table alias emp2
ON ed.EmpName = emp2.Emp_Name
```

Moreover, the `LEFT JOIN Employee` won't make any sense here and which can simply be modified to below code

```
FROM Employee emp1 
INNER JOIN Employee_DataVal ed
ON emp1.Emp_ID = ed.EmpNo
AND emp.Dept_ID = ed.DeptNo
AND emp.Emp_Name = ed.EmpName <-- here by adding another join condition
```